# Not able to get Network(kb/s) Received/sent report in JTL result file in JMETER

Tags: jmeter, sftp, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to run my performance testing of file transfer over SFTP using jmeter. Jmeter sampler which i am running on a linux box using command `sh jmeter.sh -n -t SinglePart_MultipleUsersTest.jmx -l SinglePart_MultipleUsersTest.jtl &` is

**SinglePart_MultipleUsersTest.jmx**

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.*;

def jsch = new JSch()
def session = jsch.getSession("user1", "xyz", 4000) 
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
session.setPassword("password")
def sftpSession = session.connect()
def channel = session.openChannel("sftp")
channel.connect();
def channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
log.info("SFTP Connection with host is acquired" + channelSftp)
channelSftp.cd("/0002/test/upload/r9a1");
for(i = 0; i<100; i++){
    def f1 = new File("/home/dc-user/Files/test_exact5mb.txt");
    channelSftp.put(new java.io.FileInputStream(f1), f1.getName()+i);
}
session.disconnect()
```

It generates a .jtl file which i convert into html result using the below command `jmeter -g  SinglePart_MultipleUsersTest.jtl  -o OUTPUT_FOLDER`.

HTML result doesnt show the NETWORK(Kb/s) Received/Sent result in the table in html.

**jmeter.properties** used for result are:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Results file configuration
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# This section helps determine how result data will be saved.
# The commented out values are the defaults.

# legitimate values: xml, csv, db.  Only xml and csv are currently supported.
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv

# The below properties are true when field should be saved; false otherwise
#
# assertion_results_failure_message only affects CSV output
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true
#
# legitimate values: none, first, all
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=all
#
jmeter.save.saveservice.data_type=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.label=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_code=true
# response_data is not currently supported for CSV output
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
# Save ResponseData for failed samples
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.successful=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.time=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertions=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.latency=true
# Only available with HttpClient4
#jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
#jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=false
#jmeter.save.saveservice.encoding=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
# Only available with HttpClient4
jmeter.save.saveservice.sent_bytes=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.filename=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.hostname=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.sample_count=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.idle_time=true
```

I am using SFTP protocol for transfer. Using SSH SFTP protocol as jmeter plugin.
I am missing some change in order to achieve it. Any help in this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't see the number of sent bytes because I fail to see where you call [SampleResult.setBytes()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setBytes-long-) function.

In order to count the bytes sent via SFTP channel you need to implement [SftpProgressMonitor](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/SftpProgressMonitor.html)

Example code:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpProgressMonitor


class Monitor implements SftpProgressMonitor {

    org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult sampleResult

    public Monitor(org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult sampleResult) {
        this.sampleResult = sampleResult
    }

    @Override
    void init(int i, String s, String s1, long l) {
    }

    @Override
    boolean count(long l) {
        sampleResult.setBytes(sampleResult.getBytes() + l)
        return true
    }

    @Override
    void end() {
    }
}

def jsch = new JSch()
def session = jsch.getSession("user1", "xyz", 4000)
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
session.setPassword("password")
def sftpSession = session.connect()
def channel = session.openChannel("sftp")
channel.connect();
def channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
log.info("SFTP Connection with host is acquired" + channelSftp)
channelSftp.cd("/0002/test/upload/r9a1");
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    def f1 = new File("/home/dc-user/Files/test_exact5mb.txt");
    channelSftp.put(new java.io.FileInputStream(f1), f1.getName() + i, new Monitor(SampleResult));
}
session.disconnect()
```

More information: [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter/)

Comment: Hi Dmitri - Tried with the above snippet, able to fetch `received` kb/s but `sent` as zero. Latency is also zero. Anything else i need to add in order to receive these two.